# How to post xml to servlet using selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

Mine is logistics related web app, We need to create multiple jobs based on xml posted by SALOG API.

I want to create more shipments by posting the xml's to servet and this would be done using selenium. I can't proceed to implement this.

Is there a chance to post an xml to servlet using selenium?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use direct HTTP Request for this instead of seeking how to do this using Selenium.

If you use Java you can use a wide range of libraries that ease this work.